# Default action in MVC4

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-routing

I have a controller called `Entry` that has three ActionResults: `View`, `New`, and `Edit`.

The `View` action accepts a string parameter representing a specific Entry object.

I'm trying to figure out how to not show the word "View" in the URL. In other words, I'd like it to act like a default action.

Ideally I would like the URLs read as:

> - **/entry/2DxyJR** for a given entry
> - **/entry/new** to create a new entry
> - **/entry/edit/2DxyJR** to edit a given entry

I believe this can be accomplished with a custom route but am unsure how to actually do it. This route works for hiding "View", however `/new` and `/edit` don't work.

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Entry",
    url: "entry/{id}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Entry", action = "View", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

Sorry for the extreme noobishness of this, but I'm still trying to wrap my head around how routing works.

Comment: You will need two similar route for the `/new` and the `/edit`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to be sure you put the more specific ones on top, so the entry/id will have to be last, because it appears you have string based id's.

This will  match the most explicit (new) first, then if there's edit in the url, then if not fall through to the view action.

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Entry",
    url: "entry/new",
    defaults: new { controller = "Entry", action = "New" }
);

routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Entry",
    url: "entry/edit/{id}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Entry", action = "Edit", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);

routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Entry",
    url: "entry/{id}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Entry", action = "View", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

Comment: That worked. I thought about doing something similar but I felt like it was too verbose for something so (seemingly) simple.

Answer (score 1):

I think a route constraint implementation that passes all strings behind "entry/" but excepts the words like view, edit and new, so the "Default" route can handle the. Something like:

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");


            routes.MapRoute(
                "EntryView",
                "Entry/{identifier}",
                new { controller = "Entry", action = "View" },
                new { identifier = new NotEqual(new string[]{"View", "Edit" , "New"}) }

            );
            routes.MapRoute(
                            "Default", // Route name
                            "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
                            new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
                        );
        }
```

Here is the NotEqual class:

```
public class NotEqual : IRouteConstraint
    {
        private string[] _match;

        public NotEqual(string[] match)
        {
            _match = match;
        }

        public bool Match(HttpContextBase httpContext, Route route, string parameterName, RouteValueDictionary values, RouteDirection routeDirection)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < _match.Length; i++)
            {
                if (String.Compare(values[parameterName].ToString(), _match[i], true) == 0)
                {
                    return false;
                }
            }
            return true;
        }
    }
```

I tested it and it worked, I found it as I needed it on http://stephenwalther.com/archive/2008/08/07/asp-net-mvc-tip-30-create-custom-route-constraints.aspx